# Good practice: Keeping local variable scope VS dependency injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection, scope, guice

Good practices dictate that variables should be declared as local as possible. This however, is getting in the way of the good practices of dependency injection for the sake of unit testing.

Example:

```
Class A {

    public A() {}

    public void start() {
        Map<Integer, VirtualMachine> vms = VirtualMachine.getAllVMs();

        // more code here
    }
}
```

Now I can't unit test the `start()` method. (`getAllVMs()` happens to be a static method in this case, but it could've just as easily been a `new` object. note: I don't want to use `powermock`).

So what I can do is use `google guice` to inject it, but if I do that, I need to give `vms` class scope, even if I am only using it locally in that method.

Is there a way around this or am I forced to make it a class field?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that variable's value is needed only in the single method call, then *pass it as a method parameter*. If it applies across a number of independent method calls, providing a common context, then the logical scope is "larger" than the method, and it should be a field.

Comment: Hmmm so you're saying that I should inject the `Map` into a field of the previous class (the one that calls this one's `start()` method), and then pass it as a parameter every time the `start()` method is called?

Comment: @Tiberiu If it varies between invocations of `start()`, yes (or pass in some `VirtualMachineProvider` that you can mock). If you only `start()` once, then you should probably pass the map into the class's constructor.